# Some doubts about Netty NioEventLoop

Tags: java, netty

Netty version 4.1.1.7 Final. I wonder what the if is for and why you must select#selectNow before working on the task.

```
// io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop#select

      private void select(boolean oldWakenUp) throws IOException {
             // ...
             for (;;) {
          long timeoutMillis = (selectDeadLineNanos - currentTimeNanos + 500000L) / 1000000L;
                if (timeoutMillis <= 0) {
                    if (selectCnt == 0) {
                        selector.selectNow();
                        selectCnt = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }

           // ...
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this line is reached it is already decided that the select operation should not wait for some `Channel` / `SelectionKey` to become ready or wait for a timeout.

But for the further operations on the `selector` it is still important to know which `Channel`s are ready to be processed and therefore update the `SelectionKey`s.

And this is what [`Selector.selectNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#selectNow()) does:

> Selects a set of keys whose corresponding channels are ready for I/O operations.
>
> This method performs a non-blocking selection operation. If no channels have become selectable since the previous selection operation then this method immediately returns zero.